# When manipulating a RichEditBox at runtime (search for links & setting them, etc.), code continues executing out of turn

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, uwp

I have a RichEditBox that I use as a common RTF editor. When the user types text into the editor, the TextChanging event repeatedly searches the content for links, and then marks them. It also does other simple formatting to the link, like change the color of the link, etc.

My SetHyperlinks() function that does this work, however, still appears to be executing, even though the system has moved on to the next line of code below that function. But the code below the SetHyperlinks() function call depends on the SetHyperlinks() function finishing its work before executing. Am I making sense?

```
RichEditBox_TextChanging(RichEditBox sender, RichEditBoxTextChaningEventArgs args)
{
    this.SetHyperlinks(sender.Document.Selection);

    // Before SetHyperlinks() finishes, the code below it starts executing.
    // It is as if the SetHyperlinks() method needs an awaiter.

    var variableThatDependsOnSetHyperlinksResults;
}
```

Also, I am using UWP if that matters. Thanks.

Comment: is `SetHyperlinks` async?

Comment: Nah. There is no code within that function that requires it. None of the code uses async calls. This is weird.

Comment: @LeBrownJones what happens if you make the RichEditBox_TextChanging  async and you `await Task.Run(()=>{this.SetHyperlinks(sender.Document.Selection);});`

Comment: @LeBrownJones also why are you using TextChanging rather than TextChanged?

Comment: @erotavlas TextChaning allows you to make modifications to the presentation of text just before it is rendered on-screen. This also helps prevent the text flickering you might experience when making certain "style" changes to text. TextChanged displays the text first, and then after it is displayed the text styling will be applied to it. It doesn't make sense for what I wish to achieve. Also, it does nothing to fix the issue I have

Comment: @erotavlas But Overall, it is a fact that functions return before the RichEditBox finishes manipulating text... at least in situations where the work you are performing on the text might take a little longer than a few milliseconds. I put together a quick test to prove my point. This is just sad. Microsoft should at least provide an event for this. Maybe they would call it "TextStyleChanged" or something. But yea download a trial version of my app, EliteNote from the Microsoft Store and you will get an idea of the type of editor I've put togetehr.

Comment: @LeBrownJones ok, I was only asking because I read this - "limit code within the TextChanging event handler primarily to inspecting and updating the Document property. Attempting to perform other actions, such as showing a popup or adding/removing elements from the visual tree, might cause potentially fatal errors that can lead to a crash. We recommend that you perform these other changes either in a TextChanged event handler, or run them as a separate asynchronous operation" wasn't sure what kind of changes to the UI you were doing.

Comment: @LeBrownJones another idea, can you run whatever continuation code in TextChanged()?  Will SetHyperLinks() be completed by the time TextChanged is triggered?

Comment: @erotavlas all of the changes I've made within TextChanging directly involves making changes only to the actual text editor. But it is something to consider further. And I get the same result using TextChanged() as well. I'm taking a different approach to see if it works, though.

Comment: I'm not sure what happen in your code. If `SetHyperlinks` is a synchronization method, the following code will not be executed until this method finished. Please provide a [mcve], I could help you diagnose this issue.